# Are questions about crunchyroll on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Are questions about crunchyroll (and other popular anime-focused software) on topic here?  I figured the users most likely to be able to answer a question about crunchyroll would be here, but there is a webapps SE site.  I know Arqade takes questions about Steam, which in itself is not a game.

Comment: I would say off-topic as you are talking about software, not anime.

Comment: @MiharuDante True, but who would best know Anime-focused software?  My bet would be Anime & Manga.

Comment: When you talk about Anime-focused software, what would you imagine would be appropriate questions if this was on-topic?

Comment: This would greatly help in identifying what you would consider asking about in the category [anime-focused-software], and why you would consider this on-topic.

Comment: @MiharuDante Continuing with the Crunchyroll example, a user can ask what benefits a paid-member gets over watching for free.

Comment: Okay. I will think about it. Sounds like a possibility. If a question similar to this is asked, we may need to tweak it so that it meets the desired guidelines of what are good questions on Anime and Manga.SE.

Comment: See also: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/776/would-tags-for-anime-licensors-streamers-be-a-good-idea

Answer (score 6):

I think that following Arqade's policy on Steam (cf. [this thread on meta.Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6890/why-are-steam-questions-on-topic)) is the right way to go about this. In particular, there *is* definitely merit in allowing questions about services operated by licensed vendors of anime/manga/etc, such as Crunchyroll, Funimation, etc. Whether or not services operated by other parties (e.g. MAL, etc.) should be on topic is a separate issue (personally, I am ambivalent about this).

Note the following, partially in rebuttal to Eric:

- "You will get a better answer elsewhere" has never really been a good reason for deeming things off-topic on StackExchange. The entire point of SE (as I see it, anyway) is to *become* the place to get the best answers for your questions. Certainly, there will be some questions that are only answerable by Crunchyroll support ("I can't log into my account halp plox"), but there will be others that are answerable by ordinary folks like us (e.g. [Is the version of Madoka Magica on Crunchyroll the DVD version?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/is-the-version-of-madoka-magica-on-crunchyroll-the-dvd-version)).
- The largest community of experts on Crunchyroll/etc on StackExchange is almost certainly found here, not on Webapps.SE or anywhere else.
- I disagree that the implications are "great". There is a finite and short list of services that are Crunchyroll-like, about which I propose we accept questions. In fact, let me list most of them: Crunchyroll, Funimation, Daisuki, Aniplex Channel, Madman, and maybe Hulu and Youtube. There's probably a few UK/Australia services I missed there, but you get the idea - there aren't that many of these services out there.

This being the case, I propose that we revise our list of on-topic things to include something in the vein of [Arqade's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "Game-specific hardware and utilities" that accurately outlines the types of anime services that are kosher for this site.

Comment: **1** - Yes, we'd like to become the place with the best answers. But can we answer anything about CrunchyRoll better than their tech support, whose sole purpose is to answer those questions? Absolutely not. **2** - But the people who use CrunchyRoll here do not necessarily have answers about it, just like users of Microsoft Word should not be the target of Word-related questions. Additionally, having the knowledge here shouldn't make it on-topic. **3** - That's already seven, plus the two I listed above. Where do we stop?

Comment: @Eric **1** - No, but there are some questions we can answer _just as well_ as their tech support (cf. the one I linked), and those questions would be well-served by being asked here, where they're more findable. **2** - I see what you're saying, but I don't think there's much of a dichotomy between users and experts when it comes to Crunchyroll/etc. **3** - We stop when we've listed all the anime streamers. Streamed anime is a niche market, and there aren't all that many players in it.

Answer (score 2):

I think allowing questions about CrunchyRoll as a service has three issues:

**1. You will get a better answer elsewhere.**

It is highly unlikely that the people on our Q&A site will know better than CrunchyRoll support, a related forum, or the [Web Apps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

**2. There won't be many of these questions.**

Aside from individual issues of people who already use this site, there will be few issues brought up at all. This isn't to say we want more—I'm simply getting at the fact that there's no need for us to permit these as it's not going to bring down our current quality standards to ignore them.

**3. It has great implications.**

Say we allow questions about CrunchyRoll. What else do we allow? MyAnimeList? Hummingbird.me? The domino effect of allowing such questions would be grand.

Therefore, with these said, **I am against allowing questions about CrunchyRoll in general**.

Comment: I agree. This is exactly right. Also we must take into consideration that really asking questions about CrunchyRoll is not really on topic at all.

Comment: @MiharuDante The entire _point_ of this discussion is to determine whether or not questions about Crunchyroll are on topic or not.

Comment: I don't think it is ontopic though. The reason: Questions talking about CrunchyRoll are not anime or manga and should be based on statistics, plot holes, characters or settings in a Anime or Manga or Identification Requests so long as they are related to A&M.

Comment: **1 -** You may get a better answer elsewhere, but frankly if you wanted to ask any question on this site to the company making the anime/manga, then you would "get a better answer". **2 -** Frequency of questions is a poor excuse.  Over half of our tags are only used once ([page 8+](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tags?page=8&tab=popular)). **3 -** Limit the topics to legal sources that are anime-focused.  We can have a discussion on what sources we allow and if new ones pop up we can discuss those later.

Comment: **1** - Not true. If you email a company asking them about their anime or manga, they'll ignore you. CrunchyRoll is a user-oriented service. **2** - I'm not talking about an unused tag; I'm talking about questions regarding services in general. All those once-used tags are about specific anime(s), so they all fall under one category: anime questions. **3** - Legal sources that are anime focused? That's *huge*. Though, I admit, this is the least worrisome of the three points, IMO.

Answer (score -3):

To make my answer as simple as possible-

No, CrunchyRoll is not on-topic. My reason for this is this...

> Questions should tend to be related/affiliated towards to Anime or Manga. The purpose of this site is for people to ask about identification-requests of forgotten animes or characters you may have forgotten or would like to find out and would like to know about, statistical questions such as "Who watches the most anime", or questions that ask about an anime/mangas plot, characters, places or terminology that you may not have understood.

Just because CrunchyRoll is an anime-focused software does not mean that it is on-topic on Anime and Manga because as the name implies it does not say *Anime Software and Hardware.*

We try to encourage questions that ask about something specific and relevant to an Anime (Show/TV-Series), Manga or Light Novel.

Comment: If this is the case then all questions about anime-production, manga-production, and japanese-language should be off-topic.  None of those are "about something specific and relevant to an Anime (Show/TV-Series), Manga or Light Novel" any more than crunchyroll is relevant to watching an anime.